# inno setup excel addin installer

Tags: excel, inno-setup

I'm using the excellent [demo](http://xltoolbox.sourceforge.net/blog/2013/12/using-innosetup-to-install-excel-addins/) to make an Excel addin installer that works very well

The script installs the addin in the user directory **preventing** non administrators from using it as guests accounts

What should I do in order to install the addin in users/public or any shared dir, while keeping the functionality of the installer?

Thanks
Avi

Comment: Guest users have by default quite restrictive rights (since they are just guests). Are you sure they can even your addin if they *install* it somehow *manually* ?

Comment: They are not exactly guests. The computers are shared by many employees

Comment: Did you by any chance get a solution for non administrators?